# WordPress Backend - Custom Login Flow

Tags: hooks, login, wp-login-form

**What do I want to achieve :**
Login based on the mobile number and OTP each time the user logs in, an OTP will be sent to his number.
The OTP service is linked to an external server, meaning that, I do have an external database, and this database, has login and verify endpoints, and it has an OTP service enabled on it.

**The overall workflow is as this:**

1. user inputs the phone number and clicks on login.
2. consume login endpoint, this endpoint will send an OTP to the user's number.
3. if the response is successful, show the OTP code field, and once the user fills the Code field and submits.
4. fire the Verify endpoint,
5. if the response is successful, then **log him into WordPress**.

**What did I try so far:**

1- Created the form on HTML and javascript, and tested the API endpoints. but couldn't figure out how to link the code to the Wordpress login.

```
 //set up the verification API
            var settings = {
              url: "https:------------------------------------/login/verify",
              method: "POST",
              timeout: 0,
              headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
              },
              data: JSON.stringify({
                phoneNumber: tempPhone,
                code: tempOTP,
              }),
            };

            //-------fire verify api --------------------------
            $.ajax(settings)
              .done(function (response) {
                console.log("Can Login");

                event.preventDefault();

                //----------------------------Do Wordpress Login............


              })
              .error(function (jqXHR) {
                event.preventDefault();
                console.log("failed");
                ErrorHandule(jqXHR);
              });
          });
```

2- tried to create a new form using JetformBuilder, and added an action to that hook it to the form, just to start testing on that form but I guess, the script is not firing.

```
// Login hoocks------------------------------------------------------------------
add_action( 'jet-form-builder/custom-action/Send_OTP', function() {

    // Create a new form using JetFormsBuilder.
    $form = new Jet_Form( 'test_login' );

    // Add a phone number field to the form.
    $form->add_field( array(
        'name' => 'phone_number',
        'label' => 'Phone Number',
        'type' => 'text',
    ) );

    // Add a submit button to the form.
    $form->add_submit_button( 'Login' );

    // Hook the form submission to the custom function.
    $form->add_action( 'jet_form_submit', 'custom_login_form_submit' );

} );


function custom_login_form_submit( $form ) {

    // Get the phone number from the form submission.
    $phone_number = $form->get_field_value( 'phone_number' );

    // Make a call to the login endpoint on the external server.
    $response = wp_remote_post(
        'http://142.93.112.93:3000/auth/login/sendOTP',
        array(
            'body' => array(
                'phone_number' => $phone_number,
            ),
        )
    );

    // Check if the response was successful.
    if ( wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $response ) === 200 ) {

        // Get the OTP from the response.
        $otp = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );

        // Display an OTP field on the login form.
        $form->add_field( array(
            'name' => 'otp',
            'label' => 'OTP',
            'type' => 'text',
        ) );

    } else {

        // Display an error message.
        $form->add_error( 'Error logging in.' );

    }

}

if ( isset( $_POST['otp'] ) ) {

    // Make a call to the verify endpoint on the external server.
    $response = wp_remote_post(
        'https://example.com/api/verify',
        array(
            'body' => array(
                'phone_number' => $phone_number,
                'otp' => $_POST['otp'],
            ),
        )
    );

    // Check if the response was successful.
    if ( wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $response ) === 200 ) {

        // Log the user into WordPress.
        wp_signon( array(
            'user_login' => $phone_number,
            'user_password' => null,
            'remember' => true,
        ) );

    } else {

        // Display an error message.
        echo 'Error verifying OTP.';

    }

}
```

for 1, How can I use the function  `wp_signon` in that context?

for 2, there are a couple of things I'm not sure of,
like `$form = new Jet_Form( 'test_login' );` inside the `Jet_Form' do I enter the form name? or the form ID? or something else? I looked into their documentation but couldn't figure it out.

There is one last logical thing that I can't get over, If Wordpress only allows us to log in via username or email, how can I make it possible to log in via phone number??? and no password at all?